# Select Average of records between 2 dates SQL Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza, gaps-and-islands

I have 2 tables the first one called **Activations**, and have two columns: Line_ID, Activation_Date.
the second table Called **Speed** have columns: Line_ID, From_Date, To_Date, Record.

The First Table sample:

```
|Line_ID| Activation_Date|
|-------+----------------|
|123456 | 1-Jan          |
|345678 | 2-Jan          |
|987654 | 3-Jan          |
...
```

The Second gaps and islands Table:

```
|Line_ID|From_Date| To_Date |Speed|
|-------+---------+---------+-----|  
|123456 |1-Jan    |4-Jan    |70   |
|123456 |4-Jan    |7-Jan    |51   |
|123456 |7-Jan    |10-Jan   |48   |
|123456 |10-Jan   |15-Jan   |40   |
|123456 |15-Jan   |17-Jan   |70   |
|123456 |17-Jan   |19-Jan   |54   |
|123456 |19-Jan   |21-Jan   |94   |
|123456 |21-Jan   |28-Jan   |91   |
|123456 |28-Jan   |31-Jan   |35   |
...
```

I need to join the Activation table With the Records table to add 4 columns to the Activation table but with some concerns,

- The 1st one: The Average of Speed of the Records' first 7 days from the Activation_Date.
- The 2nd: The Average of Speed of the Records' second 7 days from the Activation_Date.
- The 3ed: The Average of Speed of the Records' third 7 days from the Activation_Date.
- The 4th: The Average of Speed of the Records' fourth 7 days from the Activation_Date.

the result will be like the below

```
|Line_ID| Activation_Date|AVG_SPEED_Week1|AVG_SPEED_Week2|AVG_SPEED_Week3|AVG_SPEED_Week4|
|-------+----------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------|
|123456 | 1-Jan          |60.5           |44             |72.6           |91             |
...
```

The result exploration

```
AVG_SPEED_Week1: Average of Speed in the 1st 7 days starting Records.From_Date: 1-Jan Records.To_Date: 7-Jan
AVG_SPEED_Week2: Average of Speed in the 2nd 7 days starting Records.From_Date: 8-Jan Records.To_Date: 14-Jan
AVG_SPEED_Week3: Average of Speed in the 2nd 7 days starting Records.From_Date: 15-Jan Records.To_Date: 21-Jan
AVG_SPEED_Week4: Average of Speed in the 2nd 7 days starting Records.From_Date: 22-Jan Records.To_Date: 28-Jan
```

Comment: I don't understand the second table.  Is it always one day in duration?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have edited the sample of the second table to be gaps and Islands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expand the data and aggregate:

```
with s as (
      select s.*, s.from_date + n.idx * interval '1 day' as dte
      from speed s join
           _V_VECTOR_IDX n
           on s.to_date <= s.from_date + n.idx * interval '1 day'
     )
select a.line_id,
       avg(case when s.dte between a.activation_date and a.activation_date + interval '6 day' then s.speed end),
       avg(case when s.dte between a.activation_date  + interval '7 day' and a.activation_date + interval '13 day' then s.speed end),
       avg(case when s.dte between a.activation_date  + interval '14 day' and a.activation_date + interval '20 day' then s.speed end),
       avg(case when s.dte between a.activation_date + interval '21 day' and a.activation_date + interval '27 day' then s.speed end)
from activations a left join
     s
     on a.line_id = s.line_id
group by a.line_id, a.activation_date;
```

This assumes the time periods are less than 1000 days or so.

Comment: I applied the mentioned code but it didn't gives me true results. If the Active_Date for Line_ID is 2020-08-19 what will be the From_Date and To_Date for the first AVG? and why DTE column is 2 days after the From_Date

Comment: @AhmedAbdelkader . . . My understanding is that this should do what you want, but perhaps you need to add or subtract a day to get the exact results.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to test it but how about that?:

```
SELECT a.Line_ID
,a.Activation_Date 
,CASE WHEN a.Activation_Date >= s.From_Date AND a.Activation_Date <= s.To_Date AND DATEADD(day,-7,s.To_Date) >= a.Activation_Date THEN AVG(SUM(s.Speed)) END AVG_SPEED_Week1
,CASE WHEN a.Activation_Date >= s.From_Date AND a.Activation_Date <= s.To_Date AND DATEADD(day,-14,s.To_Date) >= a.Activation_Date AND DATEADD(day,-7,s.From_Date) >= a.Activation_Date THEN AVG(SUM(s.Speed)) END AVG_SPEED_Week2
,CASE WHEN a.Activation_Date >= s.From_Date AND a.Activation_Date <= s.To_Date AND DATEADD(day,-21,s.To_Date) >= a.Activation_Date AND DATEADD(day,-14,s.From_Date) >= a.Activation_Date THEN AVG(SUM(s.Speed)) END AVG_SPEED_Week3
,CASE WHEN a.Activation_Date >= s.From_Date AND a.Activation_Date <= s.To_Date AND DATEADD(day,-28,s.To_Date) >= a.Activation_Date AND DATEADD(day,-21,s.From_Date) >= a.Activation_Date THEN AVG(SUM(s.Speed)) END AVG_SPEED_Week4
FROM Activations a
JOIN Speed s 
ON a.Line_ID=s.Line_ID
GROUP BY a.Line_ID, a.Activation_Date
```

I assumed that you don't need to dynamicaly count and generate average speed by any number of weeks, that 4 weeks is enough.

It definitely needs testing.